# Error "Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content."

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I wanna connect my Laravel project to parse-server. And I follow the step in https://github.com/LaravelParse/Laravel-Parse

when I run this command:

```
composer require laravel-parse/parse
```

Then I got an error:

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

I also tried to add in **composer.json** file:

```
"require": {
    "laravel-parse/parse": "^3.0"
}
```

My Laravel version is: 5.7.18

Comment: What other errors you are getting?

Comment: @ Prashant Deshmukh : Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: Try running `composer install -vvv`. This will give you more verbose output

Comment: What is your laravel version, if you see package composer.json file it support till  laravel 5.4

Comment: That repository wasn't updated for more than two years. If you check `composer.json` requirements, you'll see that it supports up to Laravel 5.4

Comment: my laravel version is : 5.7.18

Answer (score 0):

Package's [composer.json](https://github.com/LaravelParse/Laravel-Parse/blob/master/composer.json#L19)(Read Lineno 18,19) says this laravel must be up to `Laravel 5.4`. You can not use this laravel **5.5, 5.6, 5.7**, it's incompatible.

if you want use this([Laravel Parse](https://github.com/LaravelParse/Laravel-Parse)) you need **laravel 5.4**

**NOTE:** I tested in Laravel version 5.5,5.6 and 5.7, it is now not supported

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

`laravel-parse/parse` is old and unmaintained. [Last release was 2017](https://github.com/LaravelParse/Laravel-Parse/releases) which is "forever ago" in software lifetime.

My advice is to find an alternative library that does what you want instead.

### Details

`laravel-parse/parse`, even the latest version (3.0.0) depends on an obsolete package, `illuminate/support`.

In Laravel 5.5, `illuminate/support` was removed and is now provided by `laravel/framework`. `laravel/framework` now lists `illuminate/support` as a conflicting package.

```bash
composer require laravel/framework 5.5.\*
composer require laravel-parse/parse
--> Fails
```

I was able to get this to install only when I downgraded Laravel to 5.4.x (5.4.36):

```bash
composer require laravel/framework 5.4.\*
composer require laravel-parse/parse
--> Succeeds
```